# How to get command Line arguments in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CommandLinetoolApplication {

@Value("${person.name}")
private String name;

public static void main(String... argv) {
    SpringApplication.run(CommandLinetoolApplication.class, argv);
 }  
}
```

I am using eclipse so setting run configuration as
      **-Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--person.name=firstName**

But when run my application,I am getting exception as 
      "Could not resolve placeholder 'person.name' in value "${person.name}"

Comment: https://memorynotfound.com/spring-boot-passing-command-line-arguments-example/

Comment: @burm87 This is the first link if you google how to pass command Line Arguments in spring boot..I gone through this

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the `@Value` is in the main class. Have you tried adding it to a Controller class for example?

Comment: Docs ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-use-short-command-line-arguments

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This code works just fine (Spring Boot 2.1.4):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements ApplicationRunner
{

    @Value("${person.name}")
    private String name;

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run( DemoApplication.class, args );
    }

    @Override
    public void run( ApplicationArguments args ) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println( "Name: " + name );
    }
}
```

Command line:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--person.name=Test
```

The output:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.4.RELEASE)

2019-04-28 22:51:09.741  INFO 73751 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on xxx-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 73751 (/Users/strelok/code/demo-sb/target/classes started by strelok in /Users/strelok/code/demo-sb)
2019-04-28 22:51:09.745  INFO 73751 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-04-28 22:51:10.943  INFO 73751 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 16.746 seconds (JVM running for 23.386)
Name: Test
```

Comment: can i use ${persion.name} inside @importresource annotation

Comment: And if I want to pass multiple parameters with same logic?? I'm trying with something like  -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--person.name=Test --person.surname=Test2 but doesn't work

Comment: spring boot app is a JAR that's executed on systems with no maven installed...

Comment: Works on spring boot 3.1.0 for me. CoderJammer I put quotes around my 2 params and both make it in: -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--oauth2.client-id=DDD --oauth2.client-secret=GGG"

Answer (score 10):

You need to add a configuration property `person.name=firstName` in your `application.properties`

OR

Implement interface `ApplicationRunner` and override its `run` method(Correct way to read command line argument)

Example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements ApplicationRunner {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Application started with command-line arguments: {}", Arrays.toString(args.getSourceArgs()));
        logger.info("NonOptionArgs: {}", args.getNonOptionArgs());
        logger.info("OptionNames: {}", args.getOptionNames());

        for (String name : args.getOptionNames()){
            logger.info("arg-" + name + "=" + args.getOptionValues(name));
        }

        boolean containsOption = args.containsOption("person.name");
        logger.info("Contains person.name: " + containsOption);
    }
}
```

Comment: Output is : - NonOptionArgs: [-Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--person.name=Name]
OptionNames: []Contains person.name: false

Comment: person.name is false..why?My run configuration is -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--person.name=Name

Comment: if i set run configuration as **--person.name=Name** it become true..But in spring boot we don't pass argument like this

Comment: You only copied this code from https://memorynotfound.com/spring-boot-passing-command-line-arguments-example/

Comment: `@Value("${person.name}")` does not read for command line. It reads from application.properties

Comment: Yes..Then will get that property?

Comment: To get the property from command line, implement 'ApplicationRunner' interface

Comment: Isn't there any other way?

Comment: Other ways can be explored at [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Comment: I can confirm this works when building with `maven clean package` and running with `java -jar /path/to/target.jar` (Spring Boot 2.7.16). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to change your eclipse VM arguments as **-Dperson.name=dhanraj**

One more thing is there is no use to add **private String name;** in main class.
Because main method is static method, so you need to create object to access **name** 
variable and ultimately new object gives you null value not the value you set **dhanraj**.

So Use this variable in Controller or Service part.