# How to set system property when running a spring boot app in intellij?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I want to set a system property when running a spring boot application in IntelliJ, and then get it in my program. I am using IntelliJ Idea CE.

Initially I tried in a normal Java project (not spring or maven). I just set the value in "VM Options" in run configurations (Ex: -DpropertyName=propertyValue). And then I ran the main function, I was able to access it by `System.getProperty("propertyName")`.

Now I want to do the same with my spring boot project. Its packaging is war. As I am using Community Edition, I run the project by running the maven command spring-boot:run. How do I pass a system property here?

I have tried adding the property in "VM Options" in the run configuration.

I have tried below commands -

```
spring-boot:run -DpropertyName=propertyValue

spring-boot:run --propertyName=propertyValue

spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-DpropertyName=propertyValue"
```

But in all approaches, when I am getting the property value in my method, it gives null.

Any suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT** Adding code snipped as requested

```
public static boolean isSomething() {
    return !StringUtils.equals(System.getProperty("propertyName"), Constants.CONSTANT_VALUE);
}
```

Comment: Hey, its already discussed. Please use -Dprop=val in VM arguments. This can be accessed using System.getProperty("prop"). If this a program argument, then it can be accessed using @Value("${program-arg}"). Follow these links [JVM args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635176/how-to-pass-jvm-arguments-in-springboot) 
   [program arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55868420/how-to-get-command-line-arguments-in-spring-boot)

Comment: Tried it. It is even showing in console. But System.getProperty still returns null. Thinking of some work around now.

Comment: post your code for clarity. you might be missing something