# How to pass programs arguments to spring boot command line application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, command-line-arguments

Java program usually have an option on eclipse to pass the arguments:
[image]

I'm trying to do the same with springboot and maven, but there is no option to do that
[image]

How can I pass the arguments to the main class?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // disabled banner, don't want to see the spring logo
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(EnvioTelesapApplication.class);
    app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);

    app.run(args);
}
```

EDIT :

Using -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="T111111,SS" is taking all as one argument

Comment: Check `args` variable.

Comment: I'm sorry but I dont understand what you mean

Comment: You main method have parameter `args`. Command line arguments stored in that array.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Do what? Arguments already passed to main class.

Comment: I think you are not understanding me, I'm triying to execute springboot app as maven and I need to pass the arguemnt, I'm using -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="T111111,SS" but they are receiving as one argument and not two

Comment: Oh. You have to split it uself.  Use `"aaa,bb".split(",")` and you get array containing `"aaa"` and `"bb"`.

Comment: I can see that.. , but is this the proper way to do it ? I mean.. usually in a normal java app you include both and you dont have to split and AFAIK either in springboot..

Comment: Java doesn't split arguments. OS does. In case of properties OS is not involved

Comment: If you see the fist image I posted, I'm passing two argument and it's not necessary to split, java is including it in arg array, every argument in one position

Comment: Yes. It only works for `main` arguments, because OS process them that way. It doesn't happened anywhere else.

Comment: yeah but tat's what I'm sending... main arguments

Comment: why can't you as everybody else and use the spring boot configurations to pass parameters instead of trying to parse / receive ourself with main parameters?

Comment: I'm triying to do that with  -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="argOne,argTwo" but it only take one

Comment: you can get the property value in any spring bean with `@Value("${foo}")` where `foo` is the name of your parameter. And you need to use named parameters as I have provided in my example '-Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--argOne=value,argTwo=value'. Check some spring boot tutorial to make the concepts clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get command Line arguments in spring boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55868420/how-to-get-command-line-arguments-in-spring-boot)

Comment: Yes, that should be good, but what happen when it is executed in an external way, I mean using command line java -jar myjar.jar one two . It is going to understand the arguments?

Comment: Then it would be `java -jar myjar.jar --argOne=value --argTwo=value`. You can also use property files or environment variables (check the link in my answer to see how to do it).

Answer (score 3):

When using spring boot you probably should be taking advantages of `application.properties` file and overriding them as needed (including via command line).
Still, you don't see the 'arguments' tabs as you're running your spring application as a maven build rather than a Java application. In this case, you'd need to pass the arguments as part of the maven goal itself:

- Spring Boot 1.x: `spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments=--spring.main.banner-mode=off,--customArgument=custom`
- Spring Boot 2.x: `spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--spring.main.banner-mode=off,--customArgument=custom`

Check how the configuration works in spring in more details: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config

**Edit**:

Once the properties are defined (in a `application-properties` file, command line arguments, environment variable, etc.) it can be retrieved by means of `@Value("${foo}")` where `foo` is the property name.

Also, if you are interested in passing command line arguments to a Spring Boot application running via a jar file, the syntax would be: `java -jar myjar.jar --argOne=value --argTwo=value` as well documented in
[Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config)

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not helpful , do you have any example?