# Reading environment variables values through a REST endpoint in Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, environment-variables

I am passing environment variables to run the spring boot application.

Now I want to expose an **endpoint to get the value of all the environment variables** getting used in my running application to debug some issue.

Is there any way to do this? Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55868420/how-to-get-command-line-arguments-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

You need a endpoint like this

```
@GetMapping("env")
public Map<String, String> getEnv() {
    return System.getenv();
}
```

If you also want all the application properties try

```
@Autowired
AbstractEnvironment env;

@GetMapping("env")
public Map<String, Object> env() {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap();
    for (PropertySource<?> propertySource : env.getPropertySources()) {
        if (propertySource instanceof MapPropertySource) {
            map.putAll(((MapPropertySource) propertySource).getSource());
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Hi @James,

I tried this but its not giving me the environment variable passed to my application while running this. I also want to get the values of all the properties defined in the application.yml. could you please help?

Comment: Updated to include properties not just environment vars as the question requested.